# R: Months on x axis and a line for every year

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I'm trying to plot a dataset like the one in the picture.

[Example dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2xxt.png)

I want a graph for every description with months on the x axis and a line for every year.
I'm using the following code

```
UniqueObjects <- unique(df$description)

for (i in UniqueObjects){
  ggplot(df, aes(month, value, color = year)) +
    geom_line()
 
  }
```

My graph doesn't show the result i want.
[Exapmple Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqyqS.png)

Can someone please help me?

Comment: I don't think that loop is correct. You might consider facet_wrap(~description).
https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_wrap.html

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
df<-data.frame("description"=c(rep("a",7),rep("b",8),rep("c",8)),"year"=c(2014,2014,2014,2015,2015,2017,2017,2014,2014,2015,2015,2015,2015,2017,2017,2017,2014,2015,2015,2015,2017,2017,2017),"month"=c(2,3,4,1,3,8,9,5,6,2,3,4,1,2,4,1,12,10,11,12,7,8,9),"value"=c(89,78,13,25,45,11,12,3,6,8,34,56,86,99,88,44,23,11,5,7,78,11,12))

for(i in unique(df$description)){

  dfsubset<-subset(df,df$description==i) 

  assign(paste0("plot_",i),ggplot(dfsubset,aes(x=month,y=value,color=as.factor(year)))+geom_line()+theme_classic()+scale_x_continuous(breaks=1:12,limits=c(0,12)))

}

grid.arrange(plot_a,plot_b,plot_c)
```